# Rockmongo entries shows empty

Tags: php, mongodb, rockmongo

Here MongoDB entries shows 3889 , but it all shows empty.

But if i try to get with api then it showing all data.

[image]

How that is possible, and which case this things happen ??

Comment: The documents are empty in RockMongo? Is that your question? Because that sounds like a software bug which you should report to the devs of that particular software.

Comment: Ya but this is mongodb problem. In backup via export also shows empty entries.

Comment: If they're not blank using an API (I assume you are querying with the PHP driver because you've tagged PHP), then it's not a MongoDb problem, but a problem with RockMongo.

Comment: What are your versions of Rockmongo, PHP driver, and MongoDB? If you are using MongoDB 3.0+ and the WiredTiger storage engine it's likely that you need to upgrade your PHP driver to 1.6 or newer (see: [MongoDB Compatibility](http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/drivers/php/#compatibility)).

Comment: i am using mongodb 2.4.6 & other database showing fine. i have filed an issue on rockmongo github repo

Answer (score 2):

This started happening to me recently also, to check simply go in to the mongo console, and type:

```
db.collection.find()
```

Have a look at your data, <s>you'll</s> you may find one of the document entries is assigned the value of `NaN`.

How can this occur? At least in Javascript, if a variable doesn't exist when sent to `collection.update()` it becomes `NULL`, if you then add to it, it becomes 'NaN'.

This is at-least one case when the RockMongo PHP code bugs out and only shows the title and no data of a document.